# Changing from upper to lower case in several data frames

Tags: r

I have several data frames in the environment that I am trying to change the case of the column names in each data frame from upper to lower case. I am using `lapply` with no success.

```
df1 <- data.frame(COL1 = 1, COL2 = "test")
df2 <- data.frame(COLL = 10, COLL1 = "test")
df3 <- data.frame(COLLA = 25, COLLA1 = "test")
df4 <- data.frame(COLLAC= "dummy", COLLAC1 = "test")

dfList <- c("df1", "df2", "df3", "df4")

lapply(dfList, function (x){
  names(x) <- tolower(names(x))
})
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Add a `return(x)` to the `lapply`.

Comment: Where should I add return(x)?  After the function? Thanks.

Comment: As the last instruction of the function, not *after* it. Oh, and don't forget to assign the result `dfList <- lapply(...)`.

Comment: Also, `dfList <- c("df1", "df2", "df3", "df4")` does not work. You need `dfList <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you wish to keep all of your data frames in the global environment, this is a situation in which I would prefer using a `for` loop.  This allows you to operate within the global environment (`lapply` requires that you return something to the global environment).

```
dfList <- c("df1", "df2", "df3", "df4")
for (i in dfList){
  tmp <- get(i)
  assign(i, setNames(tmp, tolower(names(tmp))))
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Your list does not contain your data.frames. Lists are initiated with `list()`, not with `c()`. Here's a working example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(COL1 = 1, COL2 = "test")
df2 <- data.frame(COLL = 10, COLL1 = "test")
df3 <- data.frame(COLLA = 25, COLLA1 = "test")
df4 <- data.frame(COLLAC= "dummy", COLLAC1 = "test")

dfList <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4)

dfList <- lapply(dfList, function (x){
  names(x) <- tolower(names(x))
  return(x)
})

> dfList
[[1]]
  col1 col2
1    1 test

[[2]]
  coll coll1
1   10  test

[[3]]
  colla colla1
1    25   test

[[4]]
  collac collac1
1  dummy    test

names(dfList) <- paste0("df", 1:4)
list2env(dfList, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I have all my dataframes in a list. How do I put them back as dataframes?

Answer (score 1):

The other answers work great, but here is another option. Whenever I want to clean-up my column names I always turn to the `janitor` package. There are lots of options to clean up names with that package. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/janitor/janitor.pdf

```
library(purrr)
library(janitor)

list(df1, df2, df3, df4) %>% 
  map(janitor::clean_names)
#> [[1]]
#>   col1 col2
#> 1    1 test
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   coll coll1
#> 1   10  test
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>   colla colla1
#> 1    25   test
#> 
#> [[4]]
#>   collac collac1
#> 1  dummy    test
```